# How to get a facebook user access token?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-access-token

I was trying to use a Facebook Unity SDK. I've used a default example `TestFacebook`, set up an App Id.

I'm initializing a connection with "FB init" button, getting the following screen:

[image]

The "Find Access Token" button opens https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/?app_id=... page, that has no single sign of access token there.

[image]

Obviously an app is already created (otherwise I wouldn't have an App Id). What should I finally do to authorize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the App ID isn't owned by the user you are using the request developers.facebook.com/tools or no access tokens have been issued for your newly created app.

Check at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, select your app from the drop down and click "Get Access Token"

If your app isn't in the drop down menu, file a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)